# Is there something missing from this extremely basic but uncooperative code?

Tags: c++, build, compiler-errors, clang

I recently started learning C++, and I'm currently trying to test out the header file functionality. I wrote three simple files:

headertest.h:

```
#pragma once

class Cube
{
public:
  double getVolume();
  double getSurfaceArea();
  void setLength(double length);

private:
  double length_;
};
```

headertest.cpp:

```
#include "headertest.h"

double Cube::getVolume()
{
  return length_ * length_ * length_;
}

double Cube::getSurfaceArea()
{
  return 6 * length_ * length_;
}

void Cube::setLength(double length)
{
  length_ = length;
}
```

and main.cpp:

```
#include "headertest.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  Cube c;
  c.setLength(3.48);
  double volume = c.getVolume();
  std::cout << volume;
}
```

However, when I try to build the files, I get the following error:

```
> Executing task: /usr/bin/clang++ -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ -g /Users/jonathan/Desktop/myc++/cubetest/headertest.cpp -o /Users/jonathan/Desktop/myc++/cubetest/headertest <

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Is there something wrong about how I wrote the main.cpp file, or am I leaving out something important? I've spent all day trying to figure out this issue, and I have no idea how to get unstuck. Thank you!!

Comment: You're not compiling `main.cpp`. You need to compile *all* .cpp files.

Comment: Use a build tool like Make (CMake)